# Create private sub(?)-network with AdvancedTomato router and Apple Time Capsule …

Tags: router, vpn, subnet, private-vlan

In the next time, I’m connecting to the internet via my neighbor’s router/connection (VDSL) and I want to create a secure/private sub(?)-network between my MacBook, TimeCapsule and the neighbor’s router/the internet.

As Apple’s TimeCapsule can’t handle OpenVPN—and a VPN-Service is probably the way to go for creating a secure connection—I thought I’d also have to set up an OpenVPN router—maybe the Netgear R7000 with AdvancedTomato—to handle the OpenVPN connection.

In my humble opinion, this way—MacBook/TimeCapsule to OpenVPN router—I could create a secure connection to the internet. Though, does this also work when there is another router between my OpenVPN router and the router connecting to the internet?

Comment: This question appears to be about home networking, which is specifically off-topic in NE - see the help. Network Engineering is not "just any question about networking"...

Comment: Sorry. Maybe an admin or a moderator can move the question to the right place.